# Obtain the last weekday in a month using lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm trying to get the last weekday of a month using lubridate. I tried writing

```
> lubridate::ceiling_date(as.Date("2023-12-22"), 'month') - lubridate::wday(1)
[1] "2023-12-31"
```

but I get the last day of the month, which in this case is a Sunday. I could write a function with a loop that keeps incrementing the argument of wdays() till I hit a weekday, but there must be a simpler way.

Sincerely with many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 4):

This function generates the last three days in the month, then filters to weekdays and takes the max. (Thanks to @r2evans for pointing out we only need the last three days rather than all days in the month.)

```r
library(lubridate)

last_weekday <- function(x) {
  last_days <- ceiling_date(x, "month") - days(1:3)
  max(last_days[wday(last_days, week_start = 1) < 6])
}

last_weekday(as.Date("2023-12-22"))
# [1] "2023-12-29"
```

Comment: I was going the same route ... you could reduce the inner-vec to just `ceiling_date(as.Date("2023-12-22"), 'month') - wday(1:3)`, filter for week-day, and `max` it. (That is, no need for a full month of days.)

Answer (score 3):

```
library(lubridate)

last_weekday <- function(x) {
  
  last_day_of_month <- ceiling_date(as.Date(x), 'month') - wday(1)
  
  if (weekdays(last_day_of_month) == "Sunday") {
   x2 <- last_day_of_month - wday(2)
  }

  else if (weekdays(last_day_of_month) == "Saturday") {
   x2 <- last_day_of_month - wday(1)
  }

  else {
    x2 <- last_day_of_month
  }
  
  x2
} 

date <- "2024-03-01"

last_weekday(date)
[1] "2024-03-29"
```

Basically check if the last day is a Saturday or Sunday, then subtract 1 or 2 respectively, otherwise return the date.

Additionally, for a vectorised approach (multiple dates) you may use a `dplyr::case_when` as follows:

```
last_weekday <- function(x) {
  
  last_day_of_month <- ceiling_date(as.Date(x), 'month') - wday(1)
  
  case_when(
    weekdays(last_day_of_month) == "Saturday" ~ last_day_of_month - wday(1),
    weekdays(last_day_of_month) == "Sunday" ~ last_day_of_month - wday(2),
    TRUE ~ last_day_of_month
    )
} 

date <- c("2024-03-01", "2024-02-01", "2023-12-07")

last_weekday(date)

#[1] "2024-03-29" "2024-02-29" "2023-12-29"
```

Comment: We could replace the `case_when` with   `last_day_of_month - match(weekdays(last_day_of_month, TRUE), c("Sat", "Sun"), 0)`

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we could exploit POSIXlt format. To months we add `1`, from days set to `1` we subtract `1` to get last day of the month `y`. Finally, in a `seq`uence from `x` minus `2` (which gives the last possible working day if `x` is Sunday) to `y`, we look for the last weekday.

```
> last_wd <- \(x) {
+   x <- as.Date(x)
+   y <- as.POSIXlt(x)
+   y$mon <- y$mon + 1L
+   y$mday <- 1L
+   Z <- Map(seq.Date, from=x - 2L, to=as.Date(y) - 1L, by='day')
+   sapply(Z, \(z) z[which.max(cumsum(strftime(z, '%u') == '5'))]) |> as.Date()
+ }
> 
> last_wd('2023-12-31')
[1] "2023-12-29"
> 
> last_wd(c('2023-12-22', '2023-12-31', '2024-03-01', '1970-01-01'))
[1] "2023-12-29" "2023-12-29" "2024-03-29" "1970-01-30"
```

*Check:*

```
> last_wd(c('2023-12-22', '2023-12-31', '2024-03-01', '1970-01-01')) |> 
+   strftime('%A')
[1] "Friday" "Friday" "Friday" "Friday"
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but here´s my `purrr` take:

```
library(tidyverse)
# ---------
lwd <- \(x) detect(ceiling_date(x, "months")-days(1:3), \(y) wday(y) %in% 2:6)

# --------
> walk(today() + months(-2:9), \(x) message(format(lwd(x), "%d/%m (%a)")))
31/01 (qua)
29/02 (qui)
29/03 (sex)
30/04 (ter)
31/05 (sex)
28/06 (sex)
31/07 (qua)
30/08 (sex)
30/09 (seg)
31/10 (qui)
29/11 (sex)
31/12 (ter)
```